# How to move lot of files to document library from a folder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, powershell

We are looking at moving files of about 350gb of files to sharepoint.
    What would be the ideal tool to use.Will powershell do the job?
Thanks in Advance
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely PowerShell is here to rescue you! Here is the small function which uploads the files from a directory `c:\myfolder\` :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null
function UploadAllFiles($WebURL, $DocLibName, $FolderPath)
{

 #Get the Web & Lists to upload the file
 $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($WebURL)
 $web= $site.OpenWeb()


#Get the Target Document Library to upload
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName)

#Get the Files from Local Folder
$Files = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath #You can filter files by: -filter “*.pdf” 

#upload the files
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    #Get the Contents of the file to FileStream 
    $stream = (Get-Item $file.FullName).OpenRead()         
    # Set Metadata Hashtable For the file - OPTIONAL
    $Metadata = @{"Country" = "United States"; "Domain" = "Sales"}                
    $uploaded = $List.Files.Add($File.Name, $stream, $Metadata, $TRUE)               
    $stream.Dispose()
}

#Dispose the site object
$site.Dispose()
}

#call the upload function
UploadAllFiles "http://testserver/sites/sales/" "Document Library Name" "c:\myfolder\"
```

Happy SharePointing! :)

Comment: Cheers taught as much

Comment: About if i have multiple folders with children.How can i copy that across.
Cheers

Comment: do you mean multiple folders in the source of the destination site?

Comment: Yes multiple folders as the source and it needs to copy across to the destination as it is?
Cheers

Comment: Any ideas on how to iterate through all the folders and add all child documents?

Comment: I'm also getting error : Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'OpenRead'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "-Recurse" option with this line below, then you will get all the child items as well.

## Get the Files from Local Folder

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath #You can filter files by: -filter “*.pdf” -Recurse
```